# What is the relation between config_RELOCATABLE and config_randomize_base?

Tags: security, kernel, aslr

config_randomize_base (KASLR) can load kernel text into random addresses in memory. As far as I could understand, config_RELOCATABLE makes kernel relocatable so that it can be allowed to be loaded to random addresses. So does it mean config_RELOCATABLE is a dependency for config_randomize_base? Can we enable config_randomize_base without enabling config_RELOCATABLE? If so, how does it work and what is the difference between them ?

Comment: "So does it mean config_RELOCATABLE is a dependency for config_randomize_base?" - Yes, it is dependency. You can easily found that if read description of `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE` option, either via `make menuconfig` or on online resource (e.g. https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RANDOMIZE_BASE.html).